# Angularjs FB login using factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I am new to angularjs.I am using factories where i have written the fb login code.
And during the last step i am sending all the data to my server where the user is registered in my database and the token is sent.

Here is the code.

```
'use strict'

APP.factory('authenticationFactory',['ENV','$http','$rootScope', function (ENV,$http,$rootScope) {

    return {

          socialLogin:function(data){
            return $http.post($rootScope.apiURL+'sociallogin',data).then(function (resp) {
               if(resp.status == 200) {
                   return resp.data;
               }
            })
        },
        fbLogin: function () {
            var FB = window.FB;
            var scopes = 'public_profile,email';

            var that = this;

            FB.login(function (response) {
                return that.facebookStatusChangeCallback(response);
            }, {scope: scopes});
        },

        facebookStatusChangeCallback: function(response){
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                var r = this.facebookApiRequest(response);
                console.log(r);
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                console.log('Please log into this app.');

            } else {
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
                console.log('Please log into Facebook.');
            }
        },

        facebookApiRequest: function (authResponse) {
            var that = this;
            var r = FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,gender,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,birthday', function (response) {
                var r = FB.api("/" + response.id + "/picture?height=720", function (pictureResponse) {
                    if (pictureResponse && !pictureResponse.error) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        response.profile_pic = pictureResponse.data.url;
                        response.access_token = authResponse.authResponse.accessToken;
                        response.provider = 'facebook';
                        response.devicetoken = '';
                        response.full_name = response.first_name+' '+response.last_name;
                        var r = that.socialPluginLogin(response).then(function (resp) {
                            return that.resp;
                        });
                        return r;
                    } else {
                        console.log('error while fatching fb pic');
                    }
                });
                console.log(r);
            });
            console.log(that);
        },

        socialPluginLogin : function (data) {
            var resp = this.socialLogin(data).then(function (resp) {
                return resp;
            });
            return resp;

        }

    };
}]);
```

I am calling the `fbLogin()` function from my controller. i need the response from the function `socialLogin()` so that i can change the state.

Where am i going wrong.??

Comment: After the http call i need that response in my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pointing in the wrong direction, another try:

Your function `fbLogin` should return a promise, which can be resolved by `socialLogin` later. Since `fbLogin` doesn't return a thing, you don't receive any signal from the completed login.

See this:

```
// We add $q here
APP.factory('authenticationFactory',['ENV','$http','$rootScope','$q', function (ENV,$http,$rootScope,$q) {

    var loginPromise;

    return {
        socialLogin:function(data){
            return $http.post($rootScope.apiURL+'sociallogin',data).then(function (resp) {
                if(resp.status == 200) {

                    // This is your connection to the controller
                    loginPromise.resolve(resp.data);

                    return resp.data;
                }
            })
        },
        fbLogin: function () {
            var FB = window.FB;
            var scopes = 'public_profile,email';

            var that = this;

            FB.login(function (response) {
                return that.facebookStatusChangeCallback(response);
            }, {scope: scopes});

            // Create and return a promise
            loginPromise = $q.defer();

            // EDIT: My fault, return the promise:
            return loginPromise.promise;
        },
        //...
```

And add this to the controller:

```
authenticationFactory.fbLogin().then(function(data){
    // Check it out:
    console.dir(data);
})
```

Additional things you should consider:

- Define your functions in the function body, not in the return statement. You can eliminate `that=this` this way
- Only return the API, not all the functions
- Read up on promises, they are the way to go in the angular world. You might as well use callbacks, but those are tedious to handle.

Comment: but from my controller i am calling fbLogin function which after series of calls call the socialLogin function

Comment: can you tell me what should i write in my controller

Comment: Getting error $q is not defined and loginPromise is not defined

Comment: Show me your updated code, or set up an example/demo/fiddle

Comment: authenticationFactory.fbLogin(...).then is not a function

Comment: My fault, return the promise, not the deferred. See changes

Answer (score 0):

Change your `socialLogin` function to below, your function would return a promise object which you can consume in `socialPluginLogin` via `then` which you are already doing.

```
socialLogin:function(data){
    return $http.post($rootScope.apiURL+'sociallogin',data)
},
```